# Why is .attr('id') undefined on click?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm trying to get the ID of a close by input field, but I only get 'undefind' as a result. I've tried `parent(), closest(), find()`, but they all return `undefined`. I must be doing something elementary wrong for this not to work.

[You can see my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctn3qqdh/2/).

PS. This JS code breaks in jsFiddle, why?

```
<input id="2" class="country-id" type="text" value="NO" />
<span id="3" class="ui-helper"></span>
<input id="4" class="country-name" type="text" value="Norway" />

// JS
$('.country-name').reset(); // <-- this gives error in jsFiddle

$.fn.reset = function() {
    var self = this; 

    $(self).on('click', function(){    
        $(self).val('');   
        //$(self).parent('.country-id').val(''); 
        alert($(self).parent('.country-id').attr('id'));      
    });
}
```

Comment: *"This JS code breaks in jsFiddle, why?"* Because you're not adding the `reset` function to jQuery instances until ***after*** you've tried to use it. So `reset` is `undefined`, and you try to call it, which causes an error.

Comment: Just a small side note; in this instance you needn't use `self`, `this` will always be sufficient. Additionally, be sure to register your function *before* calling it!

Comment: Ah - I thought because it was a function, it didn't matter where it was (like PHP functions). By the way, why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `find()` because `'.country-id'` is not a descendant of `.country-name`.

You also can't use `parent()` or `closest()` because `.country-id` is not an ancestor of `.country-name`.

`.country-id` and `.country-name` are **siblings**, so you have to use `siblings()`:

```
$.fn.reset = function() {
  var self = this; 

  $(self).on('click', function(){    
    $(self).val('');   
    alert($(self).siblings('.country-id').attr('id'));      
  });
}
```

Also, `$('.country-name').reset()` gives an error because you are calling it before the `reset` method definition. You have call it after defining the `reset` method:

```
$.fn.reset = function() {
  ...
}

$('.country-name').reset();
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a bit. You might also want to add what Arun pointd out about using `this` instead of `self`inside the click function.

Comment: @Steven yes, thanks for pointing that out. wasn't really thinking about that earlier. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `country-id` is a sibling of `country-name` not a parent so

```
$(self).siblings('.country-id').attr('id')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/601a3r4x/)

---

Also your use of `self` in the plugin is problematic because if you invoke the plugin in a jQuery object with multiple element references then it will fail

```
$.fn.reset = function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).val('');
        //$(self).parent('.country-id').val('');
        console.log($(this).siblings('.country-id').attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Wny is `self` a problem? It's just a reference to the same collection as `this`.

Comment: You're right. `$(self).on` is OK, but inside the handler it has to go back to `this` to get the element clicked on, rather than the elements bound.

Answer (score 0):

This works well

```
$('.country-name').on('click', function(){    
            $(self).val('');    
            //$(self).parent('.country-id').val('');
            alert($('.country-name').closest( "input" ).attr('id'));      
        });
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a class selector in the alert, because it won't necessarily find the same class member as the one he clicked on.

Comment: I doubt very much that this works well. He wants the ID of the `.country-id` element, it's not an ancestor of `.country-name`.

Comment: He mentioned he want to get the id of close by input field. yes class selector is not appropriate to use, but for this case is it. He can pass on anything and use `this` keyword

Comment: You do know that `closest` finds the closest **ancestor**, not the closest **sibling**, don't you?